# Spring Security blocking commandButton actions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm having some trouble with the Spring Security addition to my project. I've done the initial configuration with the automatic login form and it worked fine. However after I logged in and tried to do some action, I realized that my commandButtons are not working anymore. When I click then, nothing happens. Do I need to do any configuration in this case ?

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/login.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/404.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/error.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/access-denied.xhtml" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADORES')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="joao" password="123" authorities="ROLE_VENDEDORES" />
                <user name="jean" password="123" authorities="ROLE_ADMINISTRADORES" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Was it! Thank you very much Slava.. You saved me! Is there any problem in turning off the CSRF ?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. Also I added a link to Spring Security documentation where you can find more information on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is because of [CSRF protection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure). I wouldn't recommend you to disable it completely. Instead of I suggest to

1. try to fix the issues if it's possible
2. [disable it only for some of the URLs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/179#issuecomment-114999129)